# Is this set convex ?2

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is this set convex for every arbitrary $\alpha\in \mathbb R$?
$$\Big\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2_{++} \,\Big|\, x_1x_2\geq \alpha\Big\}$$ 
Where $\mathbb R^2_{++}=[0,+\infty)\times [0,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to relax this slightly to $x_1,x_2\geq 0$. The $\alpha< 0$ case is trivial, as others have shown. Here's another way to handle the case when $\alpha\geq 0$. First, note that
$$
x_1x_2 \geq \alpha \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \tfrac{1}{4}(x_1+x_2)^2\geq \tfrac{1}{4}(x_1-x_2)^2+\alpha
$$
You'll want to multiply out the quadratics on the right-hand side to confirm this for yourself. Take the square root of both sides:
$$
\tfrac{1}{2}|x_1+x_2|\geq \sqrt{\tfrac{1}{4}(x_1-x_2)^2+\alpha} = \left\| \begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{1}{2}(x_1-x_2) \\ \sqrt{|\alpha|} \end{bmatrix} \right\|_2
$$
But of course, under our assumptions, $|x_1+x_2|=x_1+x_2$ and $|\alpha|=\alpha$. So putting it together,
$$
x_1,x_2\geq 0,~x_1x_2 \geq \alpha \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \left\| \begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{1}{2}(x_1-x_2) \\ \sqrt{\alpha} \end{bmatrix} \right\|_2 \leq \tfrac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)
$$
which represents the composition of a convex second-order (Lorentz) cone and an affine mapping $(x_1,x_2)\rightarrow(\tfrac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2),\tfrac{1}{2}(x_1-x_2),\alpha)$.

This may seem like an awfully convoluted way to go about it. But in fact this is a common transformation in practice, because most primal-dual convex optimization solvers cannot handle the hyperbolic form directly, while the Lorentz cone is a fundamental object.

Answer (score 3):

For $\alpha\le 0$ your set equals $\mathbb R^2_{++}$, which is of course convex. For $\alpha>0$ you have $x_1,x_2\neq 0$ for all $(x_1,x_2)$ in the set and you can rewrite $x_1 x_2\ge \alpha$ as $x_2 \ge \alpha/x_1$, so your set is the region above the hyperbola $x_2=\alpha/x_1$ in $\mathbb R^2_{++}$, which is convex.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. You should separate the case $a<0$ (when it is the quadrant) and $a>0$ when it is bounded by an arc of a hyperbola.

Comment: So how we can prove that if $\lambda\in[0,1]$ and $x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2)\in R^2_{++}$ such that $x_1x_2\geq\alpha$ and $y_1y_2\geq\alpha$ then $(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) y_1)(\lambda x_2+(1-\lambda) y_2)\geq\alpha$?

Comment: @hamid expand the product, $\lambda^2(x_1 x_2 ) \geq \lambda^2 a,$ $(1-\lambda)^2 y_1 y_2 \geq (1-\lambda)^2 a,$ both by assumption. The mixed term is $\lambda(1-\lambda)(x_1 y_2 + y_1 x_2) \geq \lambda(1-\lambda) a (x_1/y_1 + y_1/x_1).$ You should be able to finish it now.